# Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I am trying to run my watchOS app and whenever I click run it gives this error. This error is not there whenever I am trying to run in the simulator, only when I run this on my physical device. I have tried everything from restarting everything, deleting cache, even deleting build folders and all.

```
Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 1005
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-11-02 07:41:25 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDECoreDeviceSideInstallAppWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///Users/abid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Halcyon-coojvzkgmktyzsainzuhkwpehwct/Build/Products/Debug/Halcyon.app";
}
--
The file couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 260
Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "Watch5,9";
    "device_osBuild" = "10.2 (21S5331f)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.7";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.40.14";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "arm64_32";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 1;
    "operation_errorCode" = 260;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.1005.NSCocoaErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDECoreDeviceSideInstallAppWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "watchos10.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "10.2";
    "sdk_variant" = watchos;
}
--
```

System Information

macOS Version 14.2 (Build 23C5030f)
Xcode 15.1 (22501) (Build 15C5042i)
Timestamp: 2023-11-02T13:11:25+05:30

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: The problem was with storage we need atleast more than 45GB of storage free I guess

Comment: No.. I found a solution for my case

Comment: The solution for my case is to use a higher version of flutter sdk version: 3.13.9

Comment: In my case issue was fixed by setting the iOS 'Product Name' back to 'Runner' again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have fixed this error turns out this is a storage issue you need at least 20-30 GB of storage free in your mac. Once I have freed up my storage the issue got solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
restarting my visual studio and xcode fixed it.